# How to use the selected date on the previous page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to use the selected date on the previous page?

We get the value date:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'method_name' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag('datetimepicker12', nil, options = { :onchange => "this.form.submit()"}) %>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def  selectday

 end

def method_name
  @date=params[:datetimepicker12]
  redirect_to selectday_path(@date)
end
```

view selectday receives parameters:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"format"=>"24-06-2015"}
```

Here it is necessary to print the selected date. Call object in selectday view, but no output it:

```
<span> <%= @date %></span>
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in previous page ?

Comment: 7urkm3n, her only calendar: `<%= form_tag :action => 'method_name' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag('datetimepicker12', nil, options = { :onchange => "this.form.submit()"}) %>
  <% end %>`

Comment: Try with `<span> <%= @date.format %></span>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like:

```
def  selectday
  @date = params[:date]
end

def method_name
  @date=params[:datetimepicker12]
  redirect_to selectday_path(date:@date)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you received format parameter in your request to selectday method then you can do as below

```
def  selectday
  @date = params[:format]
end
```

you have to use format parameter and assign it to @date variable and then you can access it in view page

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in you method selectday at the controller, you are passing a @date param to that but you are not assigning that value to @date var, so when you render that, you dont have any @date value

you need do something like, if you want send that info through params

```
def  selectday(data)
   @data=data
end
```